# How to install python on debian?

Tags: linux, debian, python

I want to know how can I download and install python on my linux VPS (with SSH access).

Comment: It would help if you provided a little more information. The version of Debian, your VPS provider. Have you searched your providers help files or done an internet search ? There are many tutorials regarding this subject, if you get stuck it's easier for us to answer a more specific question, since this is quite general. Good Luck with your efforts.

Comment: Many administrative tools are written in Python nowadays, I'd be surprised if it isn't installed already.

Answer (score 2):

Post details of what you've tried so far.

If not already tried, run `sudo apt-get install python3`

Comment: Be careful, Python 3 is a different language.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

`apt-get update && apt-get install python`

This will update package information and, if successful, install the default python package and its dependencies.

I assume you log in as root to your VPS, so no need to use `sudo`.